# Windows Batch file - Date parse inside IF does not work

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, if-statement

I'm trying to parse date inside an IF statement, my actual code is slightly more complex than one below quoted (i'd use `EnableDelayedExpansion`) but still the date parsing is behaving weird to me.

the expected output of the "ECHO" command would have been during my last attempt BK_20141111_1030.7z but it is shown as BK_20141111_10:30.7z. If i move the line

```
Set PARSEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3* delims=:, "
```

outside the IF statement the output is correctly shown. Is it possible to parse delimiters within an IF clause?

`DATE /T` stores data in format GG/MM/YYYY (or MM/GG/YYYY)
`TIME /T` stores time in format HH:mm

```
 @echo off
:cmpct

Set CURRDATE=%TEMP%\CURRDATE.TMP
Set CURRTIME=%TEMP%\CURRTIME.TMP

DATE /T > %CURRDATE%
TIME /T > %CURRTIME%

Set PARSEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=/, "
For /F %PARSEARG% %%i in (%CURRDATE%) Do SET YYYYMMDD=%%k%%j%%i

if 1==1 (
  Set PARSEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3* delims=:, "
  For /F %PARSEARG% %%i in (%CURRTIME%) Do Set HHMM=%%i%%j%%k
  echo BK_%YYYYMMDD%_%HHMM%.7z 
)
)
```

Comment: what's the output from `echo %time%` ?

Comment: and you do not need temp files .You can use directly %TIME% and %DATE% env. variables.

Comment: added the bracket no modification in output, adding echo %time% inside and outside the IF statement, the output is the following:
11:29:05,16
BK_20141111_11:29.7z 11:29:05,16

new code
`@echo off
:cmpct
Set CURRDATE=%TEMP%\CURRDATE.TMP
Set CURRTIME=%TEMP%\CURRTIME.TMP
DATE /T > %CURRDATE%
TIME /T > %CURRTIME%
Set PARSEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=/, "
For /F %PARSEARG% %%i in (%CURRDATE%) Do SET YYYYMMDD=%%k%%j%%i
echo %time%
if 1==1 (
Set PARSEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3* delims=:, "
For /F %PARSEARG% %%i in (%CURRTIME%) Do( Set HHMM=%%i%%j%%k
echo BK_%YYYYMMDD%_%HHMM%.7z %time%
)
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off 
:cmpct

 Set PARSEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3,4* delims=/, " 
 For /F %PARSEARG% %%i in ("%DATE%") Do SET YYYYMMDD=%%k%%j%%i 
rem  echo %time% 
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  if 1==1 ( 
   For /F "eol=; tokens=1,2,3* delims=:, " %%i in ("%time%") Do (
   Set HHMM=%%i%%j%%k 
   echo BK_%YYYYMMDD%_!HHMM!.7z 
   rem %time%
   )
 )

 if 2==2 (   
   For /F "eol=; tokens=1,2,3* delims=:, " %%i in ("%time%") Do (
   Set HHMM=%%i%%j%%k 
   echo BK_%YYYYMMDD%_!HHMM!.7z 
   rem %time%
   )
 )
 endlocal
```

?

**EDIT**

I saw your memo and updated my answer.
You cannot parametrize the `FOR` command with delayed expansion.

the `%variables%` are expanded during the parsing of the script.

the `!variables!`  (delayed expansion) are expanded during the execution.

But `FOR` command checks it's syntax during parsing so using `FOR !options!`  will always lead to parsing error. So the only option you have is multiple `IF` conditions or a subroutine.

Comment: sorry but you workarounded by extracting 
`Set PARSEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3* delims=:, "` 
from outside the `IF` statement, I'd like to parse the text only in case specific condition is verified.

Comment: I'm speachless, you solved my problem even without directly asking a solution for it, still, just for curiosity sake, not using delayed expansion, can you explain why 
`Set PARSEARG="eol=; tokens=1,2,3* delims=:, "`
is working fine outside the `IF` statement but it is not from within? The `FOR` statement still remains within the `IF` statement so it should not be that the real cause

Comment: @spike_ge - because of the brackets. Every variable defined/changed inside brackets take an effect when the brackets are closed - http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html